# AndEngine error on loading library

Tags: android, andengine

I have a problem while running the examples from andengine. The error I'm getting is at this line:

```
System.loadLibrary( "andenginephysicsbox2dextension" );
```

Couldn't load andenginephysics2dextension. Find library returned null. I noticed other people kept having this problem but no solution was proposed.

Any help is welcomed! Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

looks like you missed to copy the native libraries. AndEngine is now hosted on github and it is in perfectly active development! ( https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine ) more info on what changed in the new GLES2 version here: http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html#p26851

Using AndEngine as a library project is recommended and this will automatically 'copy' the native libraries to your project.

Best Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting is because you have to build the Box2D extension yourself. I think there is tutorial how to do it. However i stoped there and downloaded the demos from market. Then eventually switched to libGDX.

Comment: is libgdx better than andengine ?

Comment: It is different, can't say it is better. It forces you to go a little bit under the hood to understand things. That is good i think. Also i find the documentation for libGDX much better than for AndEngine. LibGDX seems live project and AndEngine has no commits for over 3 months since Nicholas works for Zynga. Check them both and decide which fits you best. I personally tried Cocos2D for android, AndEngine and now i use libGDX.

Comment: AndEngine has moved to github this is why it looks dead in the old repository. https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine

Comment: oh, didn't noticed that, sry for bad info. Maybe link to github from http://www.andengine.org would help ;) or at least some info at http://code.google.com/p/andengine/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6131C7A9DDCF959A

The new way of using andEngine is to include the git repos as libraries (without making any jars)