# Library andenginephysicsbox2dextension not found

Tags: android, graphics, box2d, andengine

I have used the andengine.jar file in our application. I have run the physicsexample. But it shows error Library andenginephysicsbox2dextension not found. Is there any solution to remove this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should not use andengine.jar. Instead fetch the source code from repository.
See this thread on AndEngine forums:
http://www.andengine.org/forums/announces/andengine-gles2-pre-release-on-december-23rd-t6097.html

You will need to get AndEngine and the extensions you wish to use. Then link them in your IDE. AndEngine is no longer distributed in .jar files, so the version you have is most likely very old.

Comment: Now i used AndEngine and other extensions. But same problem arise. Application crashes with same issue.

Comment: I got error on this line System.loadLibrary("andenginephysicsbox2dextension");                 In physicsworld.class

Comment: Have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740428/andengine-error-on-loading-library

Comment: i was uploaded the examples from the code.google.com. Let me try with github. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have resolved this issue after using code.google.com extension and libs file from github. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the shared object `libandenginephysicsbox2dextension.so` in `libs/armeabi`, `armeabi-v7` and `x86 physicsBox` uses native code from this library