# andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar is not added

Tags: box2d, andengine

i use andengine GLES1.i add andengin.jar to my program . i want add  **andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar** but i get force close.

my error is :

> 05-12 19:43:58.639: E/AndroidRuntime(11740): Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load
>   andenginephysicsbox2dextension: findLibrary returned null 05-12
>   19:43:58.639: E/AndroidRuntime(11740):    at
>   org.anddev.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld.(PhysicsWorld.java:30)

i study [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839786/library-andenginephysicsbox2dextension-not-found) link.but i don't know what is  **andenginephysicsbox2dextension.so**
and how i use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all andengine packets from [github](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension)

Comment: Ok.but how to add to my project?

Comment: download zyp and import the project in your eclipse or whatever you use. then u could add the project to your project or use the jar file out of the bin folder

Answer (score 0):

Your project not picking .so files from extension projects.

refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068202/2026280

or

Its very simple. Follow this simple steps

**1)** Create a new folder called **"lib"** inside the libs folder of the **main app**.

**2)** Copy all the folders ie.armabi , armabi-v7a etc from **andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/libs** folder, and paste in in the previously created **"lib"** folder in **main app**.

**3)** Now compress the **"lib"** folder as **"lib.zip"** and rename it to **"lib.jar"**.
this changes the **zip** extension to **jar**.

**4)** Finally add a line -- **compile files('lib.jar')** under dependencies{} in **Build.gradle** file of your **main app**.

**5)** Clean and build the project.